# Dataframe column: if cell contains string, return a range of digits starting at the index where string was found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe set up where i'm looking to extract out 12 digits starting at "W" in column "test"
"W" may fall at different indices throughout the column.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
          Text                                                     Result(I'd like to see)
1         SP/00016 - return of scrap from WH/MO/00003 - internal   WH/MO/00003
2         SP/28 - return of scrap from WH/MO/00074 - internal      WH/MO/00074
3         return of scrap from WH/MO/00074 - internal              WH/MO/00074
4         WH/MO/00074 - internal                                   WH/MO/00074
5         SP/00026 - return of scrap from WH/MO/00074 - internal   WH/MO/00074
```

I have tried creating a variable that identified the index value of the "W", turning that in to an integer and feeding it back in to a slice against my dataframe.
Here is a snippet of code:

```py
start1 = df1['Text'].str.index('W')
start2 = start1.astype(int)
df1['Result'] = df1['Text'].astype(str).str[start2:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract)

```py
df.Text.str.extract(r'(\w\w\/\w\w\/\d{5})')
             0
0  WH/MO/00003
1  WH/MO/00074
2  WH/MO/00074
3  WH/MO/00074
4  WH/MO/00074
```

You can also assign it to new column in the dataframe.

```
df['Result'] = df.Text.str.extract(r'(\w\w\/\w\w\/\d{5})')
```

Comment: Dishin - I'm receiving a column full of "NaN" results. Is this due to the dataframe nature of my data?

Comment: Dishin - Sorry for the comment above. I had to restart my kernel and your idea worked perfectly. I will flag as a "winner."